# python csv, writing headers only once

Tags: python, csv

So I have a program that creates CSV from .Json.

First I load the json file.

```
f = open('Data.json')
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
```

Then I go through it, looking for a specific keyword, if I find that keyword. I'll write everything related to that in a .csv file.

```
for item in data:
    if "light" in item:
       write_light_csv('light.csv', item)
```

This is my `write_light_csv` function :

```
def write_light_csv(filename,dic):

    with open (filename,'a') as csvfile:
        headers = ['TimeStamp', 'light','Proximity']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',fieldnames=headers)

        writer.writeheader()

        writer.writerow({'TimeStamp': dic['ts'], 'light' : dic['light'],'Proximity' : dic['prox']})
```

I initially had `wb+` as the mode, but that cleared everything each time the file was opened for writing. I replaced that with `a` and now every time it writes, it adds a header. How do I make sure that header is only written once?.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You could check if file is already exists and then don't call `writeheader()` since you're opening the file with an append option.

Something like that:

```py
import os.path


file_exists = os.path.isfile(filename)

with open (filename, 'a') as csvfile:
    headers = ['TimeStamp', 'light', 'Proximity']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',fieldnames=headers)

    if not file_exists:
        writer.writeheader()  # file doesn't exist yet, write a header

    writer.writerow({'TimeStamp': dic['ts'], 'light': dic['light'], 'Proximity': dic['prox']})
```

Comment: @Kos The file won't be written to the disk before while there were no operations with the file object within a `with` block, but you're right, it's a bit confusing. I changed my example.

Comment: @Kos I'm sorry, you're right, the file gets created earlier.

Comment: @igor, there is a typo on the line `file_exists`, you don't need that colon there :)

Comment: @IgorHatarist Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks you very much, It really solved my problem

Answer (score 40):

Just another way:

```
with open(file_path, 'a') as file:
        w = csv.DictWriter(file, my_dict.keys())

        if file.tell() == 0:
            w.writeheader()

        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can check if the file is empty

```
import csv
import os

headers = ['head1', 'head2']

for row in interator:
    with open('file.csv', 'a') as f:
        file_is_empty = os.stat('file.csv').st_size == 0
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        if file_is_empty:
            writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use some `flag` and run a check before writing `headers`! e.g.

```
flag=0
def get_data(lst):
    for i in lst:#say list of url
        global flag
        respons = requests.get(i)
        respons= respons.content.encode('utf-8')
        respons=respons.replace('\\','')
        print respons
        data = json.loads(respons)
        fl = codecs.open(r"C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\data1.txt",'ab',encoding='utf-8')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fl,data.keys())
        if flag==0:
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(data)
        flag+=1
        print "You have written % times"%(str(flag))
    fl.close()
get_data(urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the structure of your code and export the whole file at once?

```
def write_light_csv(filename, data):
    with open (filename, 'w') as csvfile:
        headers = ['TimeStamp', 'light','Proximity']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',fieldnames=headers)

        writer.writeheader()

        for item in data:
            if "light" in item:
                writer.writerow({'TimeStamp': item['ts'], 'light' : item['light'],'Proximity' : item['prox']})


write_light_csv('light.csv', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [csv.Sniffer](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) Class and

```
with open('my.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    if csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
    # skip writing headers
```

Answer (score 0):

**While using Pandas:** (*for storing Dataframe data to CSV file*)
just add this check before setting header property if you are using an index to iterate over API calls to add data in CSV file.

```
if i > 0:
        dataset.to_csv('file_name.csv',index=False, mode='a', header=False)
    else:
        dataset.to_csv('file_name.csv',index=False, mode='a', header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example that only depends on Python's builtin `csv` package. This method checks that the header is what's expected or it throws an error. It also handles the case where the file doesn't exist or does exist but is empty by writing the header. Hope this helps:

```py
import csv
import os


def append_to_csv(path, fieldnames, rows):
    is_write_header = not os.path.exists(path) or _is_empty_file(path)
    if not is_write_header:
        _assert_field_names_match(path, fieldnames)

    _append_to_csv(path, fieldnames, rows, is_write_header)


def _is_empty_file(path):
    return os.stat(path).st_size == 0


def _assert_field_names_match(path, fieldnames):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(reader)
        if header != fieldnames:
            raise ValueError(f'Incompatible header: expected {fieldnames}, '
                             f'but existing file has {header}')


def _append_to_csv(path, fieldnames, rows, is_write_header: bool):
    with open(path, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if is_write_header:
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

You can test this with the following code:

```py
file_ = 'countries.csv'
fieldnames_ = ['name', 'area', 'country_code2', 'country_code3']
rows_ = [
    {'name': 'Albania', 'area': 28748, 'country_code2': 'AL', 'country_code3': 'ALB'},
    {'name': 'Algeria', 'area': 2381741, 'country_code2': 'DZ', 'country_code3': 'DZA'},
    {'name': 'American Samoa', 'area': 199, 'country_code2': 'AS', 'country_code3': 'ASM'}
]

append_to_csv(file_, fieldnames_, rows_)
```

If you run this once you get the following in `countries.csv`:

```
name,area,country_code2,country_code3
Albania,28748,AL,ALB
Algeria,2381741,DZ,DZA
American Samoa,199,AS,ASM
```

And if you run it twice you get the following (note, no second header):

```
name,area,country_code2,country_code3
Albania,28748,AL,ALB
Algeria,2381741,DZ,DZA
American Samoa,199,AS,ASM
Albania,28748,AL,ALB
Algeria,2381741,DZ,DZA
American Samoa,199,AS,ASM
```

If you then change the header in `countries.csv` and run the program again, you'll get a value error, like this:

```sh
ValueError: Incompatible header: expected ['name', 'area', 'country_code2', 'country_code3'], but existing file has ['not', 'right', 'fieldnames']
```