# How to scrape data once a day and write it to csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm a **total noobie,** i'm just starting with web scraping as a hobby.

I want to scrape data from forum (total numer of post, total numer of subjects and numer of all users) from https://www.fly4free.pl/forum/

[photo of which data I want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou0HP.png)

Watching some turotirals i've came to this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime
import csv

source = requests.get('https://www.fly4free.pl/forum/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('4fly_forum.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Data i godzina', 'Wszytskich postów', 'Wszytskich tematów', 'Wszytskich użytkowników'])

czas = datetime.datetime.now()
czas = czas.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(czas)

dane = soup.find('p', class_='genmed')

posty = dane.find_all('strong')[0].text
print(posty)

tematy = dane.find_all('strong')[1].text
print(tematy)

user = dane.find_all('strong')[2].text
print(user)

print()

csv_writer.writerow([czas, posty, tematy, user])    
csv_file.close()
```

I don't know how to make it run once a day and how to add data to the file once a day. Sorry if my questions are infantile for you pros ;), it's my first training assignment.

Also my reasult csv file looks not nice, i would like that the data will nice formated into columns

Any help and insight will be much appreciated.
thx in advance
Dejvciu

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Schedule library in Python to do this.
First install it using

```py
pip install schedule
```

Then you can modify your code to run at intervals of your choice

```py
import schedule
import time

def scrape():
    # your web scraping code here
    print('web scraping')

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(scrape) # change 10:30 to time of your choice

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

This will run the web scraping script every day at 10:30 and you can easily host it for free to make it run continually.

Here's how you would save the results to a csv in a nice formatted way with filednames (czas, tematy, posty and user) as column names.

```py
import csv
from os import path

# this will avoid appending the headers (fieldnames or column names) everytime the script runs. Headers will be written to csv only once
file_status = path.isfile('filename.csv') 

with open('filename.csv', 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['czas', 'posty', 'tematy', 'user']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    if not file_status:
        writer.writeheader() 
    writer.writerow({'czas': czas, 'posty': posty, 'tematy': tematy, 'user': user})
```

Comment: awsome thanks, Do you how to make it cretate a new line in csv every time it runs. I think now its creating new file with only one data set every time.

Comment: i'm getting this after adding it:
File "C:\Users\dejvc\Desktop\tutorial\1a.py", line 36
    print('web scraping')
                        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: error was due to mixing spaces and tabs, i've fixed it

Comment: I have edited the answer. It will append the data each time to the previous csv file in a nice formatted manner. Consider upvoting if it helped you. :)

Comment: thx a lot, i tryied to upvote but i have to small rep ;)

Comment: @Dejvciu you can still mark it as the accepted answer to help the community :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not very experienced but I think that to do that once a day, you can use the task scheduler of your computer. That will run your script once every day. Maybe this video helps you with the task scheduler: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_EMsHlDPnE

Comment: And if your csv doesn't looks nice because there are empy lines, put that: `csv_file = open('4fly_forum.csv', 'w',newline="")`

Comment: i've added it but still i'm getting "new file" every time and i would like that every time i run a script it adds a line line to csv file

Comment: To append data to an existing file, you use mode='a', i.e., `csv_file = open('4fly_forum.csv', 'a')`.

Comment: If I'm understanding you well, then the solution would be `csv_file = open('4fly_forum.csv', 'a',newline="")`. That adds the new information maintaining the old one instead of re-writing the full file each time with just the new information.

Comment: thx it worked, but now it's adding both names of colums and data every time, how to fix it, so it will be adding only data

Comment: If you don't mind doing it non-programmatically, you could just write the names of the coloumns in the csv and delete this line: `csv_writer.writerow(['Data i godzina', 'Wszytskich postów', 'Wszytskich tematów', 'Wszytskich użytkowników'])`I'm sure there's a better way and I'll think about it but I'm not very experienced in python.

Comment: Maybe this will hep you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325622/python-csv-writing-headers-only-once