# When writing twice to a CSV it works only in a particular order

Tags: python, csv

In the example below I make two objects from a class, then write the details passed in to the CSV file. The objects and CSV file are created just fine, but depending on when I do the write - it will or will not work.

The issue is in the block:

```
# Create > Write > Create > Write
dave = Character('PC', 'Dave', 'Warrior', 10, 2, 20)
dave.write_to_csv()
dan = Character('PC', 'Dan', 'Wizard', 5, 20, 5)
dan.write_to_csv()
```

In the above order 'dan' is never added to the CSV. However, if I change it to the below, both are written as desired:

```
# Create > Create > Write > Write
dave = Character('PC', 'Dave', 'Warrior', 10, 2, 20)
dan = Character('PC', 'Dan', 'Wizard', 5, 20, 5)
dave.write_to_csv()
dan.write_to_csv()
```

What is the problem here?

**Full code:**

```
import csv

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, type, name, character_class, health, mana, strength):
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.character_class = character_class
        self.health = health
        self.mana = mana
        self.strength = strength
        print('New character made')

        with open('character_file.csv', 'w') as character_file:
            character_writer = csv.writer(character_file)
            character_writer.writerow(['Type', 'Name', 'Class', 'Health', 'Mana', 'Strength'])

    def write_to_csv(self):
        with open('character_file.csv', 'a') as character_file:
            fields = [self.type, self.name, self.character_class, self.health, self.mana, self.strength]
            character_writer = csv.writer(character_file)
            character_writer.writerow(fields)
            print(f"{self.name} added to the Character Sheet.")
            # character_file.close() <-- shouldn't be needed as 'with' contains a finally > close?


# Create > Write > Create > Write
# Creating the Character then writing to the CSV works for Dave, but Dan is NOT written
dave = Character('PC', 'Dave', 'Warrior', 10, 2, 20)
dave.write_to_csv()
dan = Character('PC', 'Dan', 'Wizard', 5, 20, 5)
dan.write_to_csv()

# Create > Create > Write > Write
# Creating BOTH Characters then writing to the CSV works for BOTH
#dave = Character('PC', 'Dave', 'Warrior', 10, 2, 20)
#dan = Character('PC', 'Dan', 'Wizard', 5, 20, 5)
#dave.write_to_csv()
#dan.write_to_csv()
```

Comment: Each time you create a `Character` instance the file is cleared. Not sure how you intended this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call the constructor of `Character`, the header is written to the csv file and all contents of the file are discarded. Try to write header only once. In [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66637445/4649452) there is a write function, which writes the header only if not already written.

Try it like this:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, type, name, character_class, health, mana, strength):
        self.type = type
        ...
        print('New character made')

    def write_to_csv(self):
        filename = 'character_file.csv'
        # write header if not already written
        if not os.path.exists(filename) or os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:
            with open(filename, 'w') as character_file:
                character_writer = csv.writer(character_file)
                character_writer.writerow(['Type', 'Name', 'Class', 'Health', 'Mana', 'Strength'])

        # write character line
        with open(filename, 'a') as character_file:
            fields = [self.type, self.name, self.character_class, self.health, self.mana, self.strength]
            character_writer = csv.writer(character_file)
            character_writer.writerow(fields)
            print(f"{self.name} added to the Character Sheet.")
```

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot @Sparkofska - works a treat.